# You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I m using google map api v3. I m using  wpestate real estate wordpress theme. This is my code in template file..

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?   
  v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
  <script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {

var input = document.getElementById('address');
var options = {

componentRestrictions: {country: "in"}
};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


//var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.52043030000, 73.85674369999);

var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 15,
//center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);

}



function codeAddress() {
 var address = document.getElementById('address').value;


 geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

 map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
  });
  } else {
  alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
  }
 });
}


 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
```

It is runnig as expected but it gives error in console "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.". Because of that map doesn't show properties on map.

Comment: Remove the first line <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

Comment: I have tried that already but  map doesnt show properties

Comment: Keep the first line, try removing the second script import i.e.. <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?   
  v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

Comment: I alredy tried that...but no luck...

Comment: I tested in local, if any one of the first two script tags are removed, that error won't show up, you check again, it will work

Comment: k i will check it again..

Comment: fyi my theme also including api

Comment: I just tested the above code you have shown, I got other errors obviously, but not the error you are asking about if we remove any one of the first script tags, but there should be one atleast

Answer (score 6):

Remove the first line:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```

You are including the Google Maps API twice.

Comment: I removed first two lines but then code for autocomplete and geocoding working fine but map doesnt show properties on map.

Comment: Not the first 2 lines, just the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, like others have found out, the *duplicate* script of the Google Maps. Please check the link below for working code.

http://jsbin.com/husahasu/1/edit

To render the map **you need to specify its centre**. It will not render without it.
You also need to add css for your elements.
Put this in the head of the document.

```
<style type="text/css">
 html { height: 100% }
 body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
 #googleMap { height: 100% }
</style>
```

Comment: Please provide your entire code (pastebin.com maybe)

Comment: The script in the link is functional, are there any errors in the console? Does the map render?

Comment: yes..there are errors.. "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

Comment: I've checked your script. You need css rules set so that the map div has a height; write the errors; check the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I inserted link to the library twice, in the top page and before div.
I delete any link and it's will work. You check links in your page.